# CannotDetermineEntityError when saving entities with TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I created a NestJS and used TypeORM for the RDBMS(I used postgres in my project).

`Post` is an `@Entity` class, `PostRepository` is a `Repository` class for `Post`.

I was trying to create `OnModuleInit` service to initialize some data.

```java
@Injectable()
export class PostsDataInitializer implements OnModuleInit {
  private data: Post[] = [
    {
      title: 'Generate a NestJS project',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Create GrapQL APIs',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Connect to Postgres via TypeORM',
      content: 'content',
    },
  ];

  constructor(private readonly postRepository: PostRepository) {}
  async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.postRepository.manager.transaction(async (manager) => {
      // NOTE: you must perform all database operations using the given manager instance
      // it's a special instance of EntityManager working with this transaction
      // and don't forget to await things here
      await manager.delete(Post, {});
      console.log('deleted: {} ');
      this.data.forEach(async (d) => await manager.save(d as Post));
      const savedPosts = await manager.find<Post>(Post);
      savedPosts.forEach((p) => {
        console.log('saved: {}', p);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

When starting up the application, I got the following error.

```sh
CannotDetermineEntityError: Cannot save, given value must be instance of entity class, instead object literal is given. Or you must specify an entity target to method call.
```

*But the above `save` was accepting an instance of `Post`*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is pretty much what the error says. You cannot pass literal objects to `.save`

```js
  private data = [
    {
      title: 'Generate a NestJS project',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Create GrapQL APIs',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Connect to Postgres via TypeORM',
      content: 'content',
    },
  ].map(data => {
    const post = new Post();
    Object.assign(post, data);
    return post;
  })
```

the above might solve this.

Comment: I used  `d as Post` to cast it to `Post`, why this does not work. What is the difference between object literal and instance in typescript?

Comment: the difference isn't up to ts but to js. `new Foo()` objects will be `instance of Foo`, while a literal object that just has the shape of `Foo` won't. And TypeORM expect to work with instances of `Foo`

Comment: btw typecasting  in strongly typed languages allow us to convert types. Since javascript is not strongly typed, the _type assertion_ that you used will no longer exist at runtime. See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PWPAdhALgE4Cuw+8hAFIQKZgAmuIAntGAFzQ7EC2ARjUIBKFAF9U41Njz5o8PgCtoAXhTpMHaABYJAblSpK8pZDiIhAOjCogA)

Answer (score 7):

You can alternatively specify the target type as per the error message like so:

```js
await manager.save(Post, d)
```

From the documentation of save() I see there is such a method as:

```js
save<Entity, T extends DeepPartial<Entity>>(targetOrEntity: EntityTarget<Entity>, entity: T, options?: SaveOptions): Promise<T & Entity>;
```

nest version 9.1.8

Comment: Works better for me than the accepted answer

Comment: This answer worked well for me.